# pypi sas7bdat to_data_frame taking too long for large data(5 GB)

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, sas

I have a 5GB SAS file and the requirment is to create parquet file in Hadoop. I am using SAS7BDAT library and using following approach which is taking more then 5 hours in creating pandas dataframe when running pyspark on client mode. Curious to know if there is any better way of doing the same.

I know there is saurfang package available which is more efficient in this case, but we do not want to use any 3rd part software.

```
f =  sas7bdat.SAS7BDAT(str(source_file))
pandas_df = f.to_data_frame()
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
del pandas_df
spark_df.write.save(dest_file,format='parquet', mode='Overwrite')
```

Comment: I would suggest trying to make Spark parallely read the file rather than pandas

Comment: Kindly suggest me with an example. I tried couple if options but it did not work out.

Comment: I don't know what your file looks like, but what's wrong with `spark.read().text(file)`?

Comment: You could also put the raw file in HDFS first, then it will be split into blocks, which get read faster in parallel. Either way, the bottleneck here is definitely pandas and the read speeds of your local drive

Answer (score 0):

Please use Spark to read the file, not Pandas

https://github.com/saurfang/spark-sas7bdat/blob/master/README.md#python-api

Add this to your packages

```
saurfang:spark-sas7bdat:2.1.0-s_2.11
```

Note, I've not personally used this, I only search for "SAS 7B DAT + Spark". If you have issues, please report here

https://github.com/saurfang/spark-sas7bdat/issues/